# Stack HTML TABLE elements one on top of each other

Tags: html, html-email, css-tables

I'm trying to create a simple HTML email design.  Within the design I want to stack more than element on top of each other, specifically, an `img` and some text on top of it.

Using `divs` and `img` tags this would be no problem but using tables feels way more clunky.  I realise that tables by their very nature are not made for stacking one on top of each other btw

I've come up with a way of getting the text over the `img` but my question would be, **is there a better way of doing this than I am?**

Also am I just setting myself up for issues when it gets rendered out by various email clients?

```
<table style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: red;">
  <tr>
    <td style="position: relative;">
      <img id="img_element" src="" style="position: relative; z-index: 1; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: yellow;">
      
      <div style="z-index: 2; position: relative; color: #000; left: 20px; top: -200px; font-size: 25px; ">
        Text goes here...
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9o3bnmas/3/

Answer (score 0):

There is *absolutely* a better way of doing it!

Email clients will do weird things to your code, starting with what they accept - or don't: looking at https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-z-index/ and https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-position/ we see that this is not going to work for the Gmails (webmail, apps, anything).

So really, I should rephrase and not be punny--there is a hacky way of doing it that mostly works.

There is a technique called 'faux absolute' for HTML email as developed by Mark Robbins https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-enhancements/faux-absolute-position.html and Steven Sayo https://sayo1337.medium.com/overlay-email-absolute-positioning-efd2f2f09ed4